# $.get request to parse API

Tags: getjson

The next step in my project is to delete this helper function and create your own function for pulling an array of strings from the parse API.  The instructions are as follows:

"You'll start interacting directly with the server, so it'll help you to know more about it.  The server is run by Parse, a flexible system for storing data that offers a structured way to access and update that information over HTTP (aka a REST API).
* You can read more about the details of that system at their API docs (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest), but remember: the less time you spend researching, the more time you'll have left to keep implementing the next step.

Time to learn about AJAX! jQuery can help a lot with that too. In fact, don't use any techniques for communicating with the server other than jQuery's AJAX library, since we've hacked it a little to simplify permissions the issues you'd encounter otherwise.
* HINT: By default, the Parse API doesn't guarantee the order of the results, so you'll want to pass them an 'order' property in the data you're sending along. "

I'm trying to understand the $.get() function as I think this is what I should be using. I would like to put the request in as part of the fetchNew function with should ideally grab data from the server and display it. Any help would be awesome. This is not an easy project, and the direction is very minimal. Any hints of the right direction would be awesome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  Chat.guide.start();
  delete Chat.display();
</script>


<h2>Borken Chat</h2>

<input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send">send
</button>



<ul class="messages">

  <script>


    var Chat_Messages=[];

    function fetchNew() {
      var PrintChat=function(Chat_Messages){
      var y=Chat_Messages.length;
      for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        $(".messages").append("<li>"+Chat_Messages[i]+"<li>");

      }
      }
    $.get("https://api.parse.com",(PrintChat),"json");
   }

   setInterval(fetchNew,3000);

   $('.send').on('click', function(){
     var message = $('.draft').val();
     Chat.send(message);
   });

  </script>

</ul>
```